# Cannot identify image file PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.9.2. When I try to process my images via a python script it works, but when I try to run this within Django, I get a "cannot identify image file PIL error" using the same functions in my Django view. What could be the issue?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from image.models import fva
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageStat
from PIL import ImageFilter
from math import log
import mysql.connector

def homepage(request):
   return render(request,'index.html',{})

def rootmeansquare( im_file ):
   im = Image.open(im_file).convert('L')
   stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
   return stat.rms[0]


def upload(request):
   filename = request.FILES['search_field']
   rms=rootmeansquare(filename)
   return render(request,'index.html',{})
```

This is the error message:

> ```
> OSError at /upload
> cannot identify image file <InMemoryUploadedFile: IMG_20160120_105936.jpg (image/jpeg)>
> Request Method: POST
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload
> Django Version: 1.9.2
> Exception Type: OSError
> Exception Value:   
> cannot identify image file <InMemoryUploadedFile: IMG_20160120_105936.jpg (image/jpeg)>
> Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open, line 2287
> Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.4.4
> Python Path:   
> ['F:\\showimages\\showimages',
>  'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
>  'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
>  'C:\\Python34\\lib',
>  'C:\\Python34',
>  'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
> Server time:    Sun, 7 Feb 2016 16:45:23 -0800
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save your file somewhere. At the moment, you are setting the in-memory file to be `filename`:

```
filename = request.FILES['search_field']
```

But then in your functions you try to open the file:

```
def rootmeansquare( im_file ):
    im = Image.open(im_file)
    stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
    return stat.mean[0]
```

I don't know exactly how your views / models are setup but trying saving the image to disk, and pass around a reference to this file. You could use this approach:

```
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
img_temp.write(filename)
img_temp.flush() 

# call function, passing in temporary image file reference
rootmeansquare(img_temp)
```